# Gatsby error page resources not found. Not rendering React. After Gatsby Build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, production

I encountered a problem during my development of my Gatsby Project. With Gatsby Develop everything is working correct but recently started the build process and deployed the website.

After I started the website on a browser I got the following error. It's regarding my innovation file in my page directory:

Error: page resources for /innovation/ not found. Not rendering React

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (page-data.json)

I thought maybe I use a component or lib that is breaking the page in prod. I revert back the source code to the template like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

import Layout from "../components/layout";
import SEO from "../components/seo";

const InnovationPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#140E55" }}>
      <SEO title="Innovation" />
      <h1>Hi from the innovation page</h1>
      <p>Welcome to innovation</p>
      <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
    </div>
  </Layout>
);

export default InnovationPage;
```

The problem unfortunately still exists. I am desperate. The view is causing a blocking that no interactivity is longer working.

My gatsby-config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Lorem Ipsum`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
    twitter: "https://twitter.com/home",
    linkedin: "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/",
    xing: "https://www.xing.com",
    youtube: "https://www.youtube.com",
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-matomo",
      options: {
        siteId: "1",
        matomoUrl: "https://analytics.safia.tech",
        siteUrl: "https://safia.tech",
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-no-index`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
      options: {
        rule: {
          include: /svg/,
        },
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
};
```

Comment: Is there a page called `innovation.js` under the pages folder? Are you importing `import React from "react";` everywhere?

Comment: @FerranBuireu yes the innovation.js page exists under the pages folder and I'm importing React in every component and index.js.

Comment: Can you provide the `gatsby-config.js`? Try removing the `gatsby-plugin-offline`

Comment: I provided it in the starter post. gatsby-plugin-offline was already commented out in my gatsby config. @FerranBuireu

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug in the current version of Gatsby. Try downgrade the packages to the latest stable working version:

```
"gatsby": "2.20.36",
"gatsby-cli": "^2.12.54",
"gatsby-image": "^2.4.13",
"gatsby-plugin-exclude": "^1.0.2",
"gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.3.11",
"gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.18",
"gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.17",
"gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.10",
"gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.0.0",
"gatsby-plugin-resolve-src": "^2.1.0",
"gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.12",
"gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.19",
"gatsby-plugin-use-query-params": "^1.0.1",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.19",
"gatsby-source-graphql": "^2.6.2",
"gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.11",
```

As shown in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19618).

Remove your `package-lock.json`, your `node_modules`, and your cache folder (`.cache`) and fix the versions to the working ones.

Comment: If I set the version of gatsby to 2.20.36 I got another error message:  WebpackError: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched. It seems like a vicious circle. The build process now fails because of the StaticQuery.

Comment: That's odd. Try disabling some plugins to see if there's an issue with them. Remember to remove the cache in all processes.

Comment: I was very curious about why this error occurs. After the build process I looked into the public folder --> page-data and found that the innovation page was not saved correct. It was saved in "Innovation" instead of innovation. I don't know why but after I rename the directory to innovation it's working. I have to figure it out why this happens and will disable some plugins to debug.

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing your browsing history

I don't know why, but clearing my browsing history fixed the problem. I noticed before I did this the browser icon was the icon for a separate gatsby project that I had been working on yesterday, so maybe something is happening where your browser is mismatching details from separate gatsby projects